# I can not seem to register a namespace

Tags: python, django

My project was running fine, but then I decided to remake the entire thing and I keep getting the same error. I am trying to link all_blogs.html to detail.html. In all_blogs.html I have this a tag: . Every time I try to runserver I get the message "NoReverseMatch at /'blog' is not a registered namespace". From what I understand, we can register a namespace by adding "app_name = (namespace)" in urls.py. I did this and yet for some reason I still get the error. I am sure it has something to do with what I have in urlpatterns. Please check out my code and github link to see the entire project.
[github](https://github.com/lukejsolomon/xworld) Thank you in advance for your efforts.
Error page:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
'blog' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
'blog' is not a registered namespace
Exception Location: C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse, line 83
Python Executable:  C:\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\webDev\\xennialsworld',
 'C:\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 20 Aug 2020 22:54:36 +0000
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from blog import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.all_blogs, name='all_blogs'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

My all_blogs.html

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
<div class="row justify-content-center my-3">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' blog.id %}">
            <h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
        </a>
        <h5 class="text-muted">{{ blog.date|date:'M d Y'|upper }}</h5>
        <h4>{{ Summary.description|striptags|truncatechars:100 }}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you keep only one urls.py in your project, you can delete app_name = 'blog' and call your href with <a href="{% url 'detail' blog.id %}">

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you keep only one urls.py in your project, you can delete app_name = 'blog' and call your href with `<a href="{% url 'detail' blog.id %}">`

If you want to register namespace:

explanations here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs